# Retrieving json data of elastic search using ajax and java script

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting stuck while retrieving data of elastic search using ajax and jquery.My html file is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Elastic Aggregations</title>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>    

    $(document).ready(function(){ 

        $("button").click(function(){


            alert("hii");

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:9200/abc/biz/_search',

                crossDomain: true,

                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    console.log(responseData);
                },
                error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {

                    alert('CORS failed - ' + textStatus);
                }
            });

        });
    }); 

    </script>


        <style>
            body {
                font: 14px sans-serif;
            }
            .arc path {
                stroke: #fff;
                stroke-width: 3px;
            }
            .node circle {
                fill: #fff;
                stroke: steelblue;
                stroke-width: 1.5px;
            }
            .node {
                font: 10px sans-serif;
            }
            .link {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #ccc;
                stroke-width: 1.5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="donut-chart"></div>
     <div id="dendrogram"></div>
     <button id="button" onClick='function()'>click me</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Error is:

```
    index.html:78 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:9200/abc/biz/_search send @ jquery.min.js:4n.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ index.html:19n.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
    index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9200/abc/biz/_search. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can suggest you 2 way.

1. Remove the function from button property cause you are not creating any function which you can trigger in onClick.

```html
<button id="button">click me</button>
```

2. Create a function for jquery and use it in onClick.

Comment: one error is resolved but still two errors are remaining that is Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9200/abc/biz/_search. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Comment: why negative point??? Its so uncomfortable. you have yo fix your url. you didn't make clear about your url mod_rewrite. have you modarate your mod_rewrite??

Comment: i am not using mod_rewrite.I think it is issue of cross domain.

Comment: I am new in stack overflow.So may be by mistake i have given negative point.

Comment: when I am changing data type as jsonp then error has been changed to _search?callback=jQuery1120030…_1463824301685&_=1463824301686:1 Uncaught